# search results displaying in larger words

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any idea why these search results are displaying products with the search term within other, larger words?

For example searching for "red" here: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=red&product_cat=rentals

Displays this product: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/product/alister-dresser/ which doesn't have the literal word "red" but it's grabbing it because of "drawe**red**"

Comment: need to see the code....

Comment: What code specifically?

Comment: I think that's the default behaviour of the WordPress search function. It's crap, isn't it? There are alternative search tools available as plugins; perhaps you can find one that plays nicely with your theme?